# Getting wrong values with Dax, avrage return wrong decimals is this a problem with numbers of days in a month

Tags: powerbi, dax

I having problem This code make the avrage on employees
but in my real data i have 24 i januari and 25 in february

The avrage sould be 24,5
But i get 24,47 There is no decimals of the count of employees

Does this code devided by month or does it include something with how many days its in a month? or how can i get this. weard value?

If there is multy rows with the same employee it sould not matter becouse its distinct.

```
   _DAXNAME =
    VAR DateChosen =
        MAX( vwDimDatum[Datum2] )
    VAR T1 =
        SUMMARIZE(
            FILTER( ALL( vwDimDatum ), vwDimDatum[Datum2] <= DateChosen ),
            vwDimDatum[Datum2],
            "Distinct Employees", [_DistinctEmployee]
        )
    RETURN
        AVERAGEX( T1, [Distinct Employees] )
```

Answer (score 2):

If you build the weighted average of your January and February numbers you get:

```
(24 * 31 + 25 * 28) / (31 + 28) = 1444 / 59 = 24.47
```

So this explains your "weird" value.

Comment: I looks i was in the right track of what the problem was, Thanks for the explanation. Can you see this solved so i get the 24.5 i want? I had some thoughts about DATESTYD But i couldent solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Peter here i have make som changes

In the Datum tabell i make new column with the format
_YYYYMM = Format(Datum2,"yyyyMM")

```
  _DAXNAME =
    VAR DateChosen =
        MAX( vwDimDatum[Datum2] )
    VAR T1 =
        SUMMARIZE(
            FILTER( ALL( vwDimDatum ), **vwDimDatum[_YYYYMM]** <= Format(DateChosen,"yyyyMM") ),<-- 2 CHANGES
            vwDimDatum[_YYYYMM], <-- 1 CHANGE
            "Distinct Employees", [_DistinctEmployee]
        )
    RETURN
        AVERAGEX( T1, [Distinct Employees] )
```